# Optimize this C Code

Tags: c, optimization

How to Optimize this piece of C code...??

```
int c = no, diff = u - d;
            while (no--)
                for (d = u; d < p[no]; d += diff)
                    c++;
```

Comment: Optimize for what? Size? Speed? Cleverness? Clarity?

Comment: With `gcc` compile with `-O2` or `-O3` flag

Comment: Sacrifice a goat and perform a ritual dance at full moon.

Comment: Maybe you should use better variable names.

Comment: If you need it to be more difficult to read then you could replace the variable names with different words. Maybe you could name them after jungle animals, or Japanese food. Thus the first line would be `int crocodile = no, diff = sushi - trout;`.

Comment: You're getting picked on for at least three reasons 1) you appear to be asking us to do your work without the courtesy writing a decent question; 2) you have asked help with the solution you *think* will work (micro-optimizing this code fragment) instead of asking us to help you solve the *problem you actually face* (what you were working on when you wrote this); and 3) if you have to ask on Stack Overflow, it is essentially certain that the compiler can do better at micro-optimization then you can (you are only going to win if you chose a better method: i.e. see #2).

Comment: Question closed while I was trying to give a substantive answer.  I agree the question was poorly posed, and probably the poster should have shown more of the work done before posting.  That said, an analysis would begin by identifying the assumptions of prior assignments (variables no, u, d, and array p), and the effect of the code in assigning values to c and diff and reassigning a value to d.  If the one posted answer has any merit, it emphasizes that any optimization is secondary to a notion of correctness.

Comment: dmckee: you can optimize the inner loop, I'm not sure the compiler will do that for you...

Comment: @yi_H: Read [Felix von Leitner's presentation](http://www.linux-kongress.org/2009/slides/compiler_survey_felix_von_leitner.pdf). These days the odds are the compiler beats you *even* if you are fairly adept.

Answer (score 2):

The best optimization, for size, speed, cleverness, clarity, and anything else you may think of, is to have no code.

So, just remove those 4 lines from your source(s) and you've optimized your code.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be correct, optimizing is trivial: Replace the whole program with a variant of http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html